# Finding All Child Entities using Query to Parent Entity in TypeORM

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, class-table-inheritance

Consider a base entity as below:

```
export abstract class Notification {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({type: "date",nullable: false})
  seenAt: Date;

  @Column({ type: "integer", nullable: false })
  priority: number;
}
```

and two child entities as below:

```
@Entity()
export class NotificationType1 extends Notification {}
```

and

```
@Entity()
export class NotificationType2 extends Notification {}
```

Is there a way to find all rows in NotificationType1 and NotificationType2 using a query to the parent class like this?

```
SELECT * FROM NOTIFICATION;
```

This query return 0 rows, although there are records in NotificationType1 and NotificationType2 tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to Select from the superclass and retrieve all the records with something like this:

```
import {getConnection} from "typeorm"; 

const user = await getConnection().createQueryBuilder() 
.select("notification") 
.from(Notification, "notification");
```

You also need to change your `abstract` class to `@TableInheritance` to leverage [Single Table Inheritance.](https://typeorm.io/#/entity-inheritance/single-table-inheritance)

This Code:

```
export abstract class Notification {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({type: "date",nullable: false})
  seenAt: Date;

  @Column({ type: "integer", nullable: false })
  priority: number;
}
```

Would become:

```
@Entity()
@TableInheritance({ column: { type: "varchar", name: "type" } })
export class Notification {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({type: "date",nullable: false})
  seenAt: Date;

  @Column({ type: "integer", nullable: false })
  priority: number;
}
```

And the Child Entity:

```
@ChildEntity()
export class NotificationType1 extends Notification {}
```

The [docs have on single table inheritance](https://typeorm.io/#/entity-inheritance/single-table-inheritance).

Comment: This is not achievable using concrete table inheritance instead of single table inheritance? I didn't want to have the notification table in the database.

Comment: Abstract inheritance is a way to create Entities that inherit all of the same properties from 'base' abstract class. For example, if I want all of my Entities to have `created_at`, `updated_at`, `status`, I would use an abstract class so I do not have to rewrite that code that defines those properties within each Entity. [docs](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/entity-inheritance). Single Table Inheritance, will allow you to create multiple "types" of the same Entity and save them in the same table in the DB.

Comment: can you query the parent with a column that is only in a subset of the children entities with single table inheritance? frustrating to have to query each child individually